# How remove auto added scripts in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, head

Original in .html file:

```
<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>
<title></title>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/src/L.Control.Zoomslider.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/src/css/l.geosearch.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/dist/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<!--

[if lte IE 8]>
              <link rel="stylesheet…

-->
</head>
```

and in FF:

```
<head>

<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"></meta>
<title></title>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/src/L.Control.Zoomslider.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/src/css/l.geosearch.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="/leaflet-0.5.1/dist/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<!--

[if lte IE 8]>
              <link rel="stylesheet…

-->
<style>

    #hook_Block_StickyBannerContainer > div > div > *:…

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.adsaway.ru/csp/js/okads.js?270994265"></script>

</head>
```

Other browsers not added this, only FF?

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: may be you have added some extension on your Firefox.disable them and check again !

Comment: i trying, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in extension "Firefox Service Platform", and after disabled working(no added scripts and styles on head). But this extension is invisible: start FF on "save mode"(with SHIFT key) and disable this extension.